# How to do a while loop with iteration counting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the activity that I am stuck on:

> Re-type and run, note incorrect behavior. Then fix errors in the code, which should print num_stars asterisks.
>
> ```
> num_stars = 3
> num_printed = 0
> while num_printed != num_starts:
>     print('*')
> ```

I don't understand how to do it. I thought I could just do:

```
while num_printed != num_stars:
   print('*')
   i=i+1
```

But it says that it's invalid.

Comment: Hang on a sec... you've got a master's in computer forensics, and you're asking about a looping question? Something doesn't quite add up here

Comment: So the while condition uses `num_printed` and `num_stars` but the body uses `i`...

Comment: @inspectorG4dget There is no need to be mean. Computer forensics is a broad, interdisciplinary field and professional masters programs can admit people who might not have a strong coding background. Regardless, this is not a *terrible* first question, as far as first questions go. At least the title is descriptive, and there is an attempt. I am the first to jump on poorly worded questions, but I don't think we should discourage people who are new to programming from asking if they ask right.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I'm sorry to have come across as mean - that was not my intent. It has happened too many times, that students post assignment questions without much effort on their part. Typically, those posts come with screenshots of the problem description without much explanation from OP. Based on those traits, I assumed (evidently incorrectly, in this case) that this was a student trying to pawn off their homework assignment on the internet. Being a teacher myself, that bothers me a lot, which is probably why I snapped, arguably harsher than I should have. Sorry if I was too hars, OP

Comment: Kelsey, go back and look again at whatever textbook you are following, about making a while loop.  Or google "python while loop example", and type in one of those examples, see it work.  Once you've seen an example work, see if you can modify it to be more like the code you are supposed to do.  Some questions to think about: what is `i`?  What is its value before you get to the loop? What do you think the purpose of `num_printed` is?  Sorry, but please work on it more: I will vote it not be visible for answering unless you do more, because answering it probably won't help anyone else.

Comment: 1st- I do not have my master's degree. I just got admitted to the program provisionally (upon completion of intro to programming.) I do not have the background and this program is challenging and I need help. Forgive me of my ignorance.

Comment: 2nd- I am not "pawning off my homework." I am not a lazy student and the fact that I have challenged myself with a master's program that I have no experience in proves that. I came to the website for help because I have been stuck on this section for DAYS. So how dare you be so rude and discouraging towards someone who is trying to learn. Thanks for the apology but check yourself before attacking a student in need of help.

Comment: 3rd- Thank you to those that attempted an explanation. I do understand basic while loops. I just don't understand how to include the iteration count for this specific problem. I know the while is a condition and as long as it is met, the loop with continue and insert the given updated output every time. Please keep my post visible because this is my one source for help while my professor is busy answering over a hundred students' questions.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve walking through this: i is the iteration count (I believe.) The value of num_stars before entering the loop is 3 and num_printed is 0. I think the purpose of num_printed is that it is going to be the output that I build off of. Is that correct?

Comment: @KelseyGreenwood - OK, that is a reasonable attempt to understand, so I will say more. In your case, num_printed needs to be the iteration count. If you look at an example based on `i`, you will see something like:  `i = 0`  `while i != number_you_want:` `...do something...` `i += 1`. Everywhere it says `i`, replace `i` with `num_printed`.  This means as the code runs, `num_printed` starts with value `0`, then next loop it is `1`, etc. At first, the `while` condition while be `true` (its NOT equal yet), so it will keep looping. When it reaches the desired value, will stop looping.

Comment: @KelseyGreenwood - ah, I see that MSeifert has shown the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increment the `num_printed` variable (what is `i`?):

```
num_stars = 3
num_printed = 0
while num_printed != num_stars:
    print('*')
    num_printed += 1
```

However I a simple `range` might be preferable:

```
for _ in range(num_stars):
    print('*')
```

Comment: Thank you for that. The +=1 is the iteration, right?

Comment: The `+= 1` increments the variable by one. So it's like having `num_printed` as iteration-counter.

Comment: What is the while condition for 
Write a while loop that prints 1 to user_num. Sample output for the given program:
1
2
3
4

Comment: @KelseyGreenwood That is a new question, so could you ask a new one? :) However don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer for this question if it solved your question (if not, could you tell me what points you don't understand so I can fix them?)

Comment: @MSeirfert I would love to accept the answer because I understand now. I can also ask the new question in a new forum. How do I accept the answer? I apologize; I am new to this website. I clicked the checkmark, so maybe that was what I needed to do?

Comment: @KelseyGreenwood Yes, it's just clicking the checkmark. Thanks for accepting! I just checked for some tutorials on `while`-loops and maybe https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm can help you for the next problem.